# Ocaml Graphics event

Tags: ocaml

I made this function here to get an event from keyboard :

```
let get_move() : string =
let e = Graphics.wait_next_event [Key_pressed] in
let ke = if e.keypressed then Printf.sprintf "%c" e.key else "" in
ke;;
```

I am making a tetris, so I would like that the bloc can go down while this function is waiting an event.

Currently, when it wait an event, it "pause" the loop.
What should I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never used `Graphics` myself, but just from reading [the documentation](https://github.com/ocaml/graphics/blob/master/src/graphics.mli) I would suggest using either [`loop_at_exit`](https://github.com/ocaml/graphics/blob/master/src/graphics.mli#L313-L319) with the `Poll` event:

```
Graphics.loop_at_exit [Key_pressed; Poll] begin fun e ->
  if e.keypressed then
    ...
  else
    ...
end
```

Or with your own loop use [`key_pressed`](https://github.com/ocaml/graphics/blob/master/src/graphics.mli#L336-L338) to check whether you can call `read_key` without blocking:

```
let get_move () : char option =
  if Graphics.key_pressed () then
    Some (Graphics.read_key ())
  else
    None
```